# Testing my UserService class, but need to mock a method that gets called at the same time

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I am testing my userService classes method, but the method I am testing makes a call to another method.

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
  HelloWorldResponse hwResponse = ....;

  expect(userDaoMock.helloWorldCall(....).andReturn(hwResponse);

  reploy();

  UserResponseCode response = userService.register(user);

  assertEquals(UserResponseCode.OK, response);
}
```

Now say my register method makes a call to another method in my userService class, how can I mock that call?

From what I understand I can't do that since I am not wrapping the entire userService class in a mock right?

**Update**

When I debug my register methods' junit test, I see this:

```
SomeThing thing = helloWorldCall(...);  // userService.helloWorldCall(...);
```

Now the method helloWorldCall just returns what a userDao returns, and I have already mocked that in my test, but for some reason it is returning null when I trace execution, so thing == null.

Why is it null, shouldn't it have the value that is returned by my mock?

The UserService#helloWorldCall code is below, again it simply returns what the userDao returns which again I have mocked as you can see above which returns that response I hard coded in my unit test.  Why is it null when I trace/debug the unit test?

```
public HelloWordResponse helloWorldCall(...) {
  return userDao.helloWorldCall(..)
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to the mock out the method if it's also in userService?

Comment: @jeff see my updates, the return value is null even though I am mocking the response.

Comment: Where is the code where you wire userDaoMock into the userService being tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a mockscontrol

```
private IMocksControl mockMaker;
```

So I have to use

```
mockMaker.replay();
mockMaker.verify();
```

It works now since I had many different mock objects.

Answer (score 0):

It kills the scope here, however you could use [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework) and work with different contexts. Both your actual service and you mock implement the same interface. In your tests you would wire the mock and at runtime the actuall implementation.